# For a UA 2019 Battle Smith artificer, does the Iron Defender's attack bonus increase with the artificer's proficiency bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, unearthed-arcana, proficiency, artificer

Does the to-hit bonus of the Iron Defender's Bite increase when the proficiency of a Battle Smith Artificer (from the [2019 artificer UA](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf)) increases?

The starting bonus is +4 (which I assume is the Iron Defender's STR modifier + proficiency bonus), but nothing in the subclass' description indicates that the bonus changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It does increase.

From the Iron Defender's stat block:

> **Might of the Master.** **The following numbers increase by 1 when your proficiency bonus increases by 1:** the iron defender’s skill bonuses, **the bonuses to hit and damage of its bite,** and the number of hit points restored by its Repair action.

Comment: That was some lack of attention of my part.

Comment: @Kuerten: Heh, to be fair, the iron defender's "traits" wouldn't have been the first place I'd look for that info either :)